# Maven rename file packaged to a jar

Tags: maven

Via Maven I'm trying to create two separate jars with a different dll in each (32 bit and 64 bit) but the dll has to end up with the same name at the root of the jar.
I can create the separate jars no problem but can't seem to find a way to rename the files.

I've tried putting the files with the same name in different directories, copying them to target and then building the jars. But because 'm putting them in separate directories they don't end up in the root of the jar.

I need this as I'm creating an Applet and deploying using Java Web Start. The dlls need to be in separate jars to target different architectures and need to be at the root
of the jar as per the JNLP spec.

Start position :

```
\src
     \main
        \resources
            rxtxSerial32.dll
            rxtxSerial64.dll
```

Desired end position :

```
native-dll-32.jar
    rxtxSerial.dll (the 32 bit version)

native-dll-64.jar
    rxtxSerial.dll  (the 64 bit version)
```

To get the separate jars I'm using maven-jar-plugin

```
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>native-dll-64</id>
                <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <classifier>native-dll-64</classifier>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/rxtxSerial64.dll</include>
                  </includes>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Maybe I need a completely new startegy?

Comment: You can rename the file using Maven-Ant-Plugin, look at Ant's move task http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create two projects for these, since you want to end up with two jar files. If the projects share common functionality in the build, you can put that into a parent POM file.

Generating multiple jar files from one project leads to trouble in most cases - I usually try to avoid that. One project - one artifact, following this rule has helped me a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks - this was indeed the simplest answer. I've now got two separate projects that just contain their own specific dll in src/main/resources and unsurprisingly I now end up with two separate jars with the right contents.  I will bear in mind your 'multiple jars from one project' comment for the future as well.

Comment: Great to hear that this worked for you. Feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer if it helped you.